# SQL - counting a column value of its joined ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to count all the upvotes, and downvotes of a post,

and it should only show if the user is a friend with another user.

**My problem is, the counting of upvotes, and downvotes is not accurate.**

example:

the post_id 5 and 4 has only 1 upvote, but the retrieved data is saying that they have 3 upvotes.

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b45cd6/5) the sqlfiddle that i created.

Comment: You should post your schema and query in the question.  Most people using mobile cannot access SQLFiddle properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try if with this small change it returns the expected output:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN vote.vote_type = 'upvote' then vote_id ELSE NULL END)) AS 'upvote', 
COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN vote.vote_type = 'downvote' then vote_id ELSE NULL END)) AS 'downvote',
```

Comment: It works. thanks broooo. haha I'm really bad with queries. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

See whether this gets you somewhere (tested in SQLite, the website doesn't work correctly).

```
SELECT vote_type, post_id, user_id, COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT * FROM post JOIN vote ON vote.post_id = post.post_id WHERE (post.user_id || "," || vote.user_id) IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id || "," || friend_id FROM friend WHERE request = 'friend'
   )
) GROUP BY vote_type;
```

The big problem with this query is the concatenation (||), which I'm sure could be made more robust.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because user_id=8 has made 3 friend requests, so your query is generating a row for each of those requests, where you only want a single row - if you changed the query like this you could avoid the multiple counts :

```
SELECT user_info.id,user_info.fb_id,user_info.profile_pic,
   user_info.fname,user_info.lname, post.post_id,post.message,post.time,post.img,post.user_id,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN vote.vote_type = 'upvote' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'upvote', COUNT(CASE WHEN vote.vote_type = 'downvote' then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'downvote'

   FROM user_info

   JOIN post
   on post.user_id = user_info.id

    LEFT JOIN vote ON
    vote.post_id = post.post_id

     WHERE EXISTS (select * FROM friend
     WHERE (friend.user_id = user_info.id OR friend.friend_id = user_info.id)
     AND friend.request = 'friend' AND (friend.user_id = 8 OR friend.friend_id = 8))

     GROUP BY post.post_id
     ORDER BY post.post_id DESC
```